# monero-wallet-rpc no longer accepting json_rpc connections

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

As of a few hours ago, I'm not able to connect to json rpc. It gives a simple connection refused error. I've tried restarting it, using this command (as I'd done previously):

```
monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18085 --wallet-file node --disable-rpc-login --prompt-for-password --tx-notify "/home/ubuntu/transaction.sh %s"
```

But I'm still getting connection refused, even though it's definitely running. I tried netstat -tulpn, and it's not showing 18085 as an open port. What am I missing here?